# Solving a telegraph equation problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following problem, where I'm kinda lost what to do:

> The voltage $v$ and current $i$ in an electrical cable along the
>   $x$-axis satisfy the coupled equations
>
> $$i_x + Cv_t+Gv = 0, \;\;\;\;\;\; v_x+Li_t+Ri= 0,$$
>
> where C, G, L and R are the capacitance, (leakage) conductance,
>   inductance, and resistance per unit length in the cable. Show that $v$
>   and $i$ both satisfy the **telegraph equation**
>
> $$u_{xx} = LCu_{tt} +  (RC+LG)u_t+RGu.$$

$u$ is a function of $x$ and $t$, i.e. $u = u(x,t)$. I have tried solving for $i$ and $v$, then taking the derivatives and inserting them into the telegraph equation, but it seemed I did something wrong...

How should I proceed here? Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer to why $i$ satisfies the equation.

You want to prove
$$i_{xx} = LXi_{tt} + (RC+LG)i_t + RGi.$$
If you multiply your second coupled equation with $G$, you get
$$Gv_x + LGi_t + RGi = 0,$$
if you derive your first coupled equation by $x$, you get
$$i_{xx} + Cv_{tx} + Gv_x = 0.$$
From the two equations, if you subtract them, you have
$$LGi_t + RGi = i_{xx} + Cv_{tx}.$$

Now, If you expand the parentheses in the original equation you want to prove, in the end, you get the value $LGi_t + RGi$ which you can now replace, giving you
$$i_{xx} = LCi_{tt} + RCi_t + i_{xx} + Cv_{tx}.$$
after canceling out $i_{xx}$, this leaves the equation $$C(Li_{tt} + Ri_t + v_{tx})=0.$$
This is easy to prove as this is just the second of the coupled equations, derived by $t$ and multiplied by $C$.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help! @5xum, by the way should there be a $C$ in place of $X$?

Comment: Of course. I fixed it already. I also checked and the same kind of playing around also works for $v$.

Answer (score 2):

Derive the first equation with respect to $x$. You get

$$ i_{xx} + C v_{tx} + Gv_x = 0.$$

Use the second equation and substitute $v_x$ into the last one, then derive the second equation with respect to $t$ in order to substitute $v_{xt}$ (obviously, Schwarz' theorem holds). Then rearranging terms you have the telegraph equation for $i$.

For $v$ is the same thing.